# Writing special characters to the console using SetConsoleOutput()

Tags: c#, console, character, ascii, utf

I'm making a console game in c# and using the win32 console IO functions for increased performance.
If I were to use the Console.Write functions in .NET to print a special ASCII character like a block, it would work. However since I'm writing to an array of CHAR_INFO structs and passing it to SetConsoleOutput(), it does not work.

For example,

```
charInfoArray[0, 0].AsciiChar = (byte)'█';
//OR
charInfoArray[0, 0].UnicodeChar = '█';

SetConsoleOutput(h, charInfoArray, new Coord(width, height), new Coord(0, 0));
```

Outputs accented 'e'.

However I can do 
    charInfoArray[0, 0].AsciiChar = (char)(byte)219; //219 being the ASCII code of '█'
But that's extremely annoying and limiting when it comes to readability.

After a bunch of google searching, I have tried a few proposed solutions like:

- SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF16), did nothing
- SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8), did nothing
- Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8, did nothing
- Crying.

At this point i'm still not sure why this is happening in the first place. Any info and/or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the main problem is readability, why don't you use a data structure (Dictionary) to store your special chars? You could give them nice keynames. Or, why not, plain methods.

Comment: Well, it really *is* an accented character.  It just happens to look like a solid block in a console window.  Because it uses a different font, one that matches the way [character codes looked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) on the original IBM PC back in the 1980s.  Setting the console output code page to utf8 is fine, but then you have to use the Unicode codepoint for that glyph, U+2588.  And change the console font.

Comment: I kind of refuse to believe that there isn't a way for me to say
Print("This is a special character: █");
And have it come out like that.

As in, not having to do special things to the character like
Print("This is a special character: " + Decode('█'));

Perhaps making a method or something that will detect the special characters in a string full of normal ones and special ones but I still don't understand the issue here, unfortunately Han's answer didn't really help me.

Comment: Also, Hans, your answer doesn't make sense because it work just fine with Console.Write(), meaning the CP and font aren't the issue.